# signalR to notify clients across all web pages in web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, push-notification, signalr

I am trying to implement a web application where the client is notified by the server using push technnology. After hours of search, I found that SignalR can be used. But can we make the notification to be displayed across the entire web application irrespective of the web page the client is accessing.

Comment: that really has less to do with how signalr works and more with how your site works. But in general I would say, yes it should work.

Comment: Think for a second: Where do you put logic that is executed for all pages in your app? 
You should put this in that place.

Comment: if I call sendnotification method of the hub from main master and access it in all the pages , will it work?

Comment: You should use the Single Page Architect, try to put everything in a single html, for your original pages, put them in different DIV blocks in that single html, and hide/show each DIV instead of jumping to another page.